# Create new column depending on values from other column

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a DataFrame that looks something like this:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df=pd.DataFrame([['vt 40462',5,6],[5,6,6],[5,5,8],[4,3,1],['vl 6450',5,6],[5,6,7],
             [1,2,3],['vt 40462',5,6],[5,5,8],['vl 658',6,7],[5,5,8],[4,3,1],['vt 40461',5,6],[5,5,8],
             [7,8,5]],columns=['A','B','C'])
```

df

```
         A  B  C
0 vt 40462  5  6
1        5  6  6
2        5  5  8
3        4  3  1
4  vl 6450  5  6
5        5  6  7
6        1  2  3
7  vt 40462  5  6
8        5  5  8
9   vl 658  6  7
10       5  5  8
11       4  3  1
12 vt 40461 5  6
13        5 5  8
14        7 8  5
```

I want to give indexes the values that are between  `vt` and `vl` in column `A` and create a new columns as :

```
         A  B  C  D
0 vt 40462  5  6  vt 40462
1        5  6  6  vt 40462
2        5  5  8  vt 40462
3        4  3  1  vt 40462
4  vl 6450  5  6  vl 6450
5        5  6  7  vl 6450
6        1  2  3  vl 6450
7 vt 40462  5  6  vt 40462
8        5  5  8  vt 40462
9   vl 658  6  7  vl 658
10       5  5  8  vl 658
11       4  3  1  vl 658
12 vt 40461 5  6  vt 40461
13        5 5  8  vt 40461
14        7 8  5  vt 40461
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another way would be to `assign` column `D` to be all values of `A` that start with a letter, and then use `df.ffill()` to get rid of `NaN`s:

```
df.assign(D=df.loc[df.A.str.contains('^[A-Za-z]', na=False), 'A']).ffill()


           A  B  C         D
0   vt 40462  5  6  vt 40462
1          5  6  6  vt 40462
2          5  5  8  vt 40462
3          4  3  1  vt 40462
4    vl 6450  5  6   vl 6450
5          5  6  7   vl 6450
6          1  2  3   vl 6450
7   vt 40462  5  6  vt 40462
8          5  5  8  vt 40462
9     vl 658  6  7    vl 658
10         5  5  8    vl 658
11         4  3  1    vl 658
12  vt 40461  5  6  vt 40461
13         5  5  8  vt 40461
14         7  8  5  vt 40461
```

Or, more or less equivalently, but in 2 steps:

```
df.loc[df.A.astype(str).str.contains('^[A-Za-z]'), 'D'] = df.A

df.ffill()
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `str.split`, if ' ' not found the it returns NaN use `ffill` to fill NaN and join fields together and assign to 'D':

```
#Thanks @user3483203 for the upgrade in syntax
df['D'] = df['A'].str.split().ffill().apply(' '.join)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
          A  B  C         D
0   vt 40462  5  6  vt 40462
1          5  6  6  vt 40462
2          5  5  8  vt 40462
3          4  3  1  vt 40462
4    vl 6450  5  6   vl 6450
5          5  6  7   vl 6450
6          1  2  3   vl 6450
7   vt 40462  5  6  vt 40462
8          5  5  8  vt 40462
9     vl 658  6  7    vl 658
10         5  5  8    vl 658
11         4  3  1    vl 658
12  vt 40461  5  6  vt 40461
13         5  5  8  vt 40461
14         7  8  5  vt 40461
```

Comment: I think you can simplify to `df.A.str.split().ffill().apply(' '.join)` (Although using a lambda for join may be clearer as to what it's doing)